# Binding an Angular Directive property to a parent Controller

Tags: angularjs

In the ma-resource-text-watch Directive I make an api call to get a list of resource texts.
I want to be able to hide the alert-component if the api doesn't return any resource texts.
Does anyone know how I might be able to do this?

```
<div ng-controller="IntroductionCntrl" class="hidden-print">
    <div class="container-fluid" ng-if="introductionResourceKey">
        <alert-component type="guidance">
            <span ma-resource-text-watch="{{introductionResourceKey}}"></span>
        </alert-component>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `ng-if="texts.length"`? Or `ng-if="dataIsLoaded && texts.length"`?

Comment: @FrankModica how and where would I declare `dataIsLoaded`?
Or how would I get access to `texts.length` if `texts` is declared as a local variable in the Directive?

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize the parent-child structure. Sounds like the directive can take in a callback to fire when the data is loaded. It can pass the texts (or just the length) to that callback. Then the parent will know when data is loaded and the number of texts.

Comment: @FrankModica Just had a look and it seems like that's exactly what I'm trying to do! Do you want to post as an answer so I can give you internet points?

Comment: I switched to `ng-show`, because if we use `ng-if` the directive won't be created at all. You might want to consider having the parent controller make the API calls though, but I'm not sure if that makes sense in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have your directive take in a callback (or expression), which it will fire when the data is loaded. For example, in the directive definition, the `scope` property can have:

```
scope: {
  onTextsLoaded: '&'
}
```

The directive can then call:

```
scope.onTextsLoaded({ texts: yourTexts })
```

And the parent controller can pass in an expression as a callback, and use `ng-show` to hide the `alert-component`:

```
<alert-component ng-show="dataIsLoaded && texts.length">
    <span ma-resource-text-watch="{{introductionResourceKey}}" on-texts-loaded="onTextsLoaded(texts)"></span>
</alert-component>
```

With the function defined like:

```
$scope.onTextsLoaded = function(texts) {
    $scope.dataIsLoaded = true;
    $scope.texts = texts;
}
```